Number of doses as a predictor in a Cox model
I have some data where time to having a relapse of a particular disease state is the outcome of interest. We are interested in assessing the 'effect' of a particular treatment on relapse risk - specifically how does this change with the number of doses of the treatment. In general the treatment is given every 6 months as an IV infusion and so a statistical point of concern here is that treatment can almost be viewed as a function of time - the longer a person is observed before either having a relapse or being censored (last follow-up visit), the more doses they will receive. Is this another form of immortal time bias?
I am also wondering whether using the number of doses as a simple continuous (integer) predictor in non-counting-process format (i.e. one row of data per person) breaks the 'looking into the future' rule (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) and would assume that it does?
I found this post which suggests how one might parameterise what I presume is also a point treatment as a tvc - but not sure that it looks correct?
Extended Cox model with continuous time dependent covariate - how to structure data?
An answer is provided that goes on to suggest using number of doses as a predictor - again I'm not convinced this is correct as it seems that is estimating risk at a point in time borrowing information from the future.
Any tips on the best approach here would be appreciated.
Thanks.
